# CSS: Scroll bars on container div when child overflows

Tags: html, css

I have two divs:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="body-content">
        <h1> HI </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

"body" has the following css:

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
}
```

"body-content" has the following css:

```
.body-content {
     background-color: white;
     height: 100%;
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-right: 5%;
}
```

This gives the the body-content nice black margins on the left and right side.
However, I would like the body div to have the scroll bars (the parent) when the child div (body-content) overflows. Right now I can only get the child div to get the scroll bars.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the 2 following changes in your css:

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: auto; /* Added */
}
.body-content {
     background-color: white;
     min-height: 100%; /* Changed from height: 100% */
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hpng1xjr/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the overflow CSS here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Specifically, you should be able to do this:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

or, if you only want to scroll vertically:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
 overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add overflow: scroll to .body style. If you want vertical scroll then use `overflow-y:scroll` or for horizontal scroll use `overflow-x: scroll`